# Access object variables outside of a function

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to get variable values that are returned as an object from within a js function.
What am I doing wrong?

```
function myFunction() {
  vara = 1;
  varb = 2;
  var myobj = {'vara': vara, 'varb': varb};
  return myobj;
}
myFunction();
var getA = myobj.vara; // Console is saying can't find variable myobj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to assign the returned object from the `myFunction()` to a variable, then you can access it, something like the following:

```js
function myFunction() {
  vara = 1;
  varb = 2;
  var myobj = { vara: vara, varb: varb };
  return myobj;
}

var obj = myFunction(); // Assign the return of the function to a variable
var getA = obj.vara; // Then you can access it

console.log(getA)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `variable` inside a function, It has `local scope` inside a function. It can not be accessed `outside`. Once you `return`, you have to `assign` some variables to access `those properties`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  vara = 1;
  varb = 2;
  // Local functaional scope
  var myobj = { vara: vara, varb: varb };
  return myobj; // return here
}
const obj = myFunction(); // capture return in obj variable

var getA = obj.vara; // access the value

console.log(getA)
```